# IE11 emulation mode emulating ie8 does't recognize indexOf polyfill

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I am trying to emulate IE8 in IE11 to validate some code changes I have made. How ever there seems to be a problem with in the emulator that prevents me from working with it.

When i called the jQuery pollyfilled method.

```
[].indexOf(1)
```

I get an error from the emulator stating the following.

> The property or method indexOf is not supported by the object

This error only occurs in the emulator. I see no problems when trying this on a real IE8 browser. jQuery is loaded in both instances and it is loaded ahead of all other Javascript code.

Does any one know how to get the emulator to behave in the same way as the real browser?

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected. Tested example bellow. Probably there's a problem in your code. It would be much easier if you'd provide the code for testing purposes.

```js
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.14
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

    var k;

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing
    //    the this value as the argument.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get
    //    internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be
    //    ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be 0.
    var n = +fromIndex || 0;

    if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
      n = 0;
    }

    // 6. If n >= len, return -1.
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 7. If n >= 0, then Let k be n.
    // 8. Else, n<0, Let k be len - abs(n).
    //    If k is less than 0, then let k be 0.
    k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    // 9. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {
      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the
      //    HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      //    i.  Let elementK be the result of calling the Get
      //        internal method of O with the argument ToString(k).
      //   ii.  Let same be the result of applying the
      //        Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to
      //        searchElement and elementK.
      //  iii.  If same is true, return k.
      if (k in O && O[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}

console.log([].indexOf(1));
```

Comment: It might be so though I expect it to be unrelated to the code where the error appears in that case. Meaning I don't quite know what to post. What makes me think its an IE11 problem is that when I load the page on chrome I can access the indexOf method via the console like so Array.prototype.indexOf()

This can't be done in IE11. I get the error message.

Comment: I'm going to try to remove all my javascript files so there is no interferance and then try again.

Comment: What did you mean by writing "When i called the jQuery pollyfilled method"? jQuery doesn't create any global polyfill for Array.prototype.indexOf method. Maybe you are looking for jQuery.inArray()? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: You are right about jQuery not creating a pollyfilled method. Yet my problem remains. When running on IE8 I have no problems but when running on the emulator the indexOf method breaks.